# How can I get access to the Soundcloud API?

Tags: soundcloud

I'm trying to access the soundcloud api. I know you need to register an app and be approved to get a token. However it seems the link to do it is currently disabled. I'm wondering if there is alternative route I can try or email I can reach out to. Any insight on this is much appreciated!

Comment: [It seems the company is having trouble](https://techcrunch.com/2017/07/12/soundshroud/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a support request for SoundCloud, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sadly this is soundclouds only avenue for support. If you go to their support page they say post here.

https://developers.soundcloud.com/support

Comment: @MikeFisher I'm very aware of this. It doesn't matter. SoundCloud doesn't get to define what is on topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

As of the time of posting, [you can't](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfNxc82RJuzC0DnISat7n4H-G7IsPQIdaMpe202iiHZEoso9w/closedform). On the right hand side of their [API docs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide), "Register App" is crossed out and noted as Unavailable.

This is most likely due to the reason that they are cutting server load to reduce cost, as they run out of runway (VC funding).